# Selecting rows in JSF using primefaces

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

I'm having some trouble when trying to select single rows in a datatable (I can't figure out  what's going on, because my code is based on the primefaces showcase).

The table is filled first with result matches, then I'm trying to select a row, and finally trying to do some process. The problem appears when I try to process that single row, none of the actual methods its being called.

```
   <h:form id="form2">
        <p:dialog header="Agregar Producto" widgetVar="dlgAgregarProducto" modal="true" width="800" height="300">  
            <h:outputText value="Código"/>   
            <h:inputText value="#{promocionController.strIdProducto}"/>
            <h:outputText value="Nombre"/>     
            <h:inputText value="#{promocionController.strNombre}"/>   
            <p:commandButton id="btnBuscarProducto" value="Buscar" action="#{promocionController.buscarProductosIdNombre}" update="tableBusqueda"/>  
            <p:commandButton id="btnAgregarProducto" value="Agregar" action="#{promocionController.agregarProductos}" />  

            <p:dataTable id="tableBusqueda" var="prod" value="#{promocionController.obtenerProductos()}" 
                         rowKey="#{prod.idProducto}" selection="#{promocionController.arrProductosSeleccionados}" selectionMode="single">

                <p:column style="width:24%">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Código"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{prod.idProducto}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:24%">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Foto"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="foto"/>
                </p:column>                

                <p:column style="width:24%">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Descripción"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{prod.descripcion}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:24%">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Marca"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value=""/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:24%">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Modelo"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{prod.modelo}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:24%">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Precio"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{prod.precio}"/>
                </p:column> 

            </p:dataTable>                            
        </p:dialog> 
    </h:form>
```

Backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "promocionController")
@SessionScoped
public class PromocionCO {
    arrProductosPromocion = new ArrayList<Producto>();
    arrProductosSeleccionados = new ArrayList<Producto>();
}
public void buscarProductosIdNombre() {
    productoDAO = new ProductoDAO();
    arrProductosBusqueda = new ArrayList<Producto>();
    arrProductosSeleccionados = new ArrayList<Producto>();
    // si la búsqueda es por nombre
    if (strIdProducto.compareTo("") == 0) {
        arrProductosBusqueda = productoDAO.obtenerProductosPorNombre(strNombre);
    } // si la búsqueda es por id
    else {
        producto = productoDAO.obtenerProductoPorId(strIdProducto);
        if (producto != null) {
            arrProductosBusqueda.add(producto);
        } else {
            arrProductosBusqueda = null;
        }
    }
}

public void agregarProductos() {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrProductosSeleccionados.size(); i++) {
        arrProductosPromocion.add(arrProductosSeleccionados.get(i));
    }
}
public ArrayList<Producto> obtenerProductos() {
    return arrProductosBusqueda;
}
public ArrayList<Producto> getArrProductosSeleccionados() {
    return arrProductosSeleccionados;
}

public void setArrProductosSeleccionados(ArrayList<Producto> arrProductosSeleccionados) {
    if (arrProductosSeleccionados != null) {
        this.arrProductosSeleccionados = arrProductosSeleccionados;
    }
}
```

Comment: Complete xhtml and also the backing bean would help others to respond on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `selection` attribute points to an `ArrayList` of `Producto` instead of a single element. Since you are using datatable with `selectionMode="single"` the `selected` attribute should point a single element in your backing bean:

```
Producto selectedProducto;

public Producto getSelectedProducto() {
    return selectedProducto;
}

public void setSelectedProducto(Producto producto) {
    selectedProducto = producto;
}
```

Finally, specify this element in your dataTable `selection`:

```
 <p:dataTable id="tableBusqueda" var="prod" selectionMode="single"
               value="#{promocionController.obtenerProductos}" 
               selection="#{promocionController.selectedProducto}">
```

Now after selecting a row the `public void setSelectedProducto(Producto producto)` method will be called.

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, it is more preferable to use getter/setter methods when pointing to a value in your backing bean:

```
<p:dataTable id="tableBusqueda" var="prod" 
             value="#{promocionController.obtenerProductos}" .../>
```

In general, an appropriate getter/setter should looks like `get<NameOfTheObject>`, in your case:

```
public List<Producto> getObtenerProductos()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. At first I was attempting to select multiple rows, so I forgot to change the ArrayList<> to the single object. 
And also thanks for the advice!